# Yii2 - Bulk checkbox by GET request

Tags: checkbox, yii2

I have a checkbox in a gridview Yii2 like this:

```
[
    'class' => 'kartik\grid\CheckboxColumn',
    'width' => '20px',
    'checkboxOptions' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
        return [
            'value' => trim($model->vessel),
        ];
    }

],
```

Then to get all the value checkbox in yii2, I use this button:

```
Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></i>&nbsp; Print All',
                        ["print-all-based-date"],
                        [
                            "class" => "btn btn-success",
                            'role' => 'modal-remote-bulk',

                        ])
```

But when in my controller that handle the the action,

```
public function actionPrintAllBasedTanggal()
{
    $request = Yii::$app->request;
    $get = $request->get();
    print_r($get);
    die();
```

I get :

```
Array
(
   [r] => iwwi/incoming/print-all-based-tanggal
   [KMTC_HOCHIMINH,OOCL_NAGOYA] => 
   [_] => 1495123320863
)
```

What it means `[KMTC_HOCHIMINH,OOCL_NAGOYA] =>` ?

I check in html, the checkbox is named `selection[]`?

I need this: `KMTC_HOCHIMINH,OOCL_NAGOYA` to get continue my app.

Answer (score 0):

may be you can use jquery for the solution.
example :

```js
   $(document).on('click','#ceklist_all',function(){

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
     
        $('.ceklist_child').attr('checked',true);
        your_variable = [];
        $('.ceklist_child:checked').map(function(key,val) {
            if(this.checked) {
               your_variable[key] = this.value;
            }
        }).get();
    }
});
```

so,. you can use the your_variable and use the ajax for submit..

```js
 $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: your_url,
                data: {
                    'your_variabel_to_post' : your_variable
                },
                success: function(data){
                   // success function
                },
                error: function(data){
                    if(data.responseText)
                        alert(data.responseText);
                },
            });
```

CMIIW,.
just the optional solution. heheh

Comment: Error occurs while snippets running.

Comment: yes.. it's just example.
sorry i'm newbie too.. heheh